# React concurrent API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

So, my current code looks something like this:

component:

```
requestDescriptions(params, bothGender) {
    if (bothGender) {
        // men request
        params.gender = 'men';
        this.props.getDescriptions(params);
        // women request
        params.gender = 'women';
        this.props.getDescriptions(params);
    } else {
        this.props.getDescriptions(params);
    }
}
```

and my action looks like this:

```
export function getDescriptions(params = { brand: null, category: null, gender: null }) {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestDescription());
    return request
        .get(`${getApiUrl()}plp?${QueryString.stringify(params)}`)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err && res.statusCode !== 404) {
                ...
            }
            if (res.statusCode === 404) {
                // HERE: 
                console.log(params.gender); 
                return dispatch(receiveEmptyDescription(params));
            }
            return dispatch(receiveDescription(res.body));
        });
};
```

}

So up until now, I hadn't noticed the error, but just did when I began testing a scenario where both API calls return a 404.

The error being that having the concurrent calls to the same endpoint is overwriting my params. When the API returns a 200, I could not see the problem. But now when I'm testing returning a 404 I can clearly see the problem.

The problem im getting lies here:

```
this.props.getDescriptions(params);
params.gender = 'women';
```

If I check the console log inside my action ( `//HERE` ) , on both cases `params.gender` displays `'women'` even though the first time around its supposed to be `'men'`

I guess this can be fixed using a promise?

Let me know if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't really that you're making parallel requests or that you're getting an HTTP2XX or an HTTP4XX.

The reason you are always seeing `gender` equal to `'women'` is that you're using the **same object instance** for both requests, i.e. `params`.

What is happening is that you set `params.gender` to be `'men'`, fire of the first request, set `params.gender` to be `'women'`, fire of the second request.

All the steps above happen synchronously, before any request is completed.

This means that long before any request is finished, `params.gender` is already equal to `'women'`.

Just send a different object to each action.

```
requestDescriptions(params, bothGender) {
    if (bothGender) {
        // men request
        this.props.getDescriptions({ ...params, gender: 'men' });

        // women request
        this.props.getDescriptions({ ...params, gender: 'women' });
    } else {
        this.props.getDescriptions(params);
    }
}
```

Since you're already using Redux, you should be aware that mutation is baaaad